# How to click on the first search results returned from expedia by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to scrape hotel reviews but struggling to click on the link of the desired hotel from returned results.  Here is my code.  The error code was an invalid selector.  May I have your suggestions on how to fix this problem?

```
# Define the name, i.e. Eden The Residence at The Sea
name = "Eden The Residence at The Sea"
# name = "Admiral Suites Bangkok"

# Invoke Chrome and go to booking.com
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
print("Accessing " + driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

# Enter hotel name, i.e. Eden The Residence at The Sea
print("Searching for {}.".format(name))
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='uitk-faux-input']").send_keys(name)
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='uitk-button uitk-button-small uitk-button-fullWidth uitk-button-typeahead uitk-type-left has-subtext']").click()

# Click search
print("Clicking search button.")
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()

# Click the hotel name, i.e. Eden the Residence at The Sea
print("Selecting {} from return list.".format(name))
time.sleep(get_random_wait())
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='app']/div[@id='app-layer-manager']/div[@id='app-layer-base']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[2]/section[2]/ol[1]/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]").click()

# results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]")
results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3[contains(text(), 'Eden the Residence at the Sea')]")

results[0].click()
```

[image]

Comment: `result` is a single element. Why have you given an `index`? Also no brackets after `click`

Comment: It failed since 

results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3[contains(text(), 'Eden the Residence at the Sea')]").  I think I pass wromg css tags but cannot figure out what is the right one.

Comment: Putting random waits is not good try to put Waits described here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution. We needed to select the right `section`

```
# Define the name, i.e. Eden The Residence at The Sea
import time

from selenium import webdriver

name = "Eden The Residence at The Sea"
# name = "Admiral Suites Bangkok"

# Invoke Chrome and go to booking.com
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/bin/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
print("Accessing " + driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

# Enter hotel name, i.e. Eden The Residence at The Sea
print("Searching for {}.".format(name))
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='uitk-faux-input']").send_keys(name)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='uitk-button uitk-button-small uitk-button-fullWidth uitk-button-typeahead uitk-type-left has-subtext']").click()

# Click search
print("Clicking search button.")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()

# Click the hotel name, i.e. Eden the Residence at The Sea
print("Selecting {} from return list.".format(name))
time.sleep(10)
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='app']/div[@id='app-layer-manager']/div[@id='app-layer-base']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[2]/section[2]/ol[1]/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]").click()

# results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]")
result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("results")
hotels = result.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
hotels[1].click()
```

Output:-

```
Accessing Expedia Travel: Vacation Homes, Hotels, Car Rentals, Flights & More
https://www.expedia.com/
Searching for Eden The Residence at The Sea.
Clicking the search button.
Selecting Eden The Residence at The Sea from the return list.
```